# Configure for one hop only

Tags: network-configuration, one-hop

I am using Tor only as a cheap proxy. I want to avoid the target website from knowing my IP address and my threat vector does not include any other types of surveillance.

Is there a way to switch to one-hop so that I can have better performance and use less resources?

Comment: Or zero-hop if that's a thing

Answer (score 2):

The [FAQ](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#ChoosePathLength) talks about this.

You should let people choose their path length.

> Right now the path
> length is hard-coded at 3 plus the number of nodes in your path that
> are sensitive. That is, in normal cases it's 3, but for example if
> you're accessing an onion service or a ".exit" address it could be 4.
>
> We don't want to encourage people to use paths longer than this — it
> increases load on the network without (as far as we can tell)
> providing any more security. Remember that the best way to attack Tor
> is to attack the endpoints and ignore the middle of the path. Also,
> using paths longer than 3 could harm anonymity, first because it makes
> "denial of security" attacks easier, and second because it could act
> as an identifier if only a few people do it ("Oh, there's that person
> who changed her path length again").
>
> And we don't want to encourage people to use paths of length 1 either.
> Currently there is no reason to suspect that investigating a single
> relay will yield user-destination pairs, but if many people are using
> only a single hop, we make it more likely that attackers will seize or
> break into relays in hopes of tracing users.
>
> Now, there is a good argument for making the number of hops in a path
> unpredictable. For example, somebody who happens to control the last
> two hops in your path still doesn't know who you are, but they know
> for sure which entry node you used. Choosing path length from, say, a
> geometric distribution will turn this into a statistical attack, which
> seems to be an improvement. On the other hand, a longer path length is
> bad for usability, and without further protections it seems likely
> that an adversary can estimate your path length anyway. We're not sure
> of the right trade-offs here. Please write a research paper that tells
> us what to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is disallowed by all standard relays in the network. There used to be a `AllowSingleHopCircuits` option that relays could set to allow this, but it [was removed](https://github.com/torproject/tor/commit/d52a1e2faaf0edf8f5899c6fa9864d0cecebf692) several years ago.